# Lipschitz-constant gradient implies bounded eigenvalues on Hessian

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-analysis, lipschitz-functions, hessian-matrix

I've read in a few places that if we have a Lipschitz gradient

$$\|\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\|\leq L\|x-y\|,\, \forall x,y, $$
we can equivalently say $\nabla^2f\preceq LI.$ But I'm having a hard time showing this. (Equivalently, I want to show $z^T \nabla^2f(x)z\leq z^TLIz=Lz^Tz,\forall\, x,z $.)

Comment: @user147263 I have a question regarding his answer, When you use mean value theorem. You will get something like: $$\|\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y)\|\le \|\nabla^2 f \| \|x-y\|$$ From this have can you judge whether $\|\nabla^2 f \| \le L$ or not? The equality in the cauchy schwarz may not be obtained?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is not true as stated. For example, the function $f(x)=x|x|$ on the real line has Lipschitz gradient, but is not twice differentiable. 
Also, the function $f(x)=-x^4$ satisfies $f''\le LI$ with $L=0$, but its gradient is not Lipschitz continuous.

The two properties are equivalent for functions that are *convex* and *twice differentiable*. For such functions, $\nabla^2 f$ is a positive semidefinite matrix, so its norm is its largest eigenvalue. Hence, 
$$\nabla^2 f \preceq LI \iff \|\nabla^2 f\|\le L \iff \|\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y)\|\le L\|x-y\|$$
where the last equivalence is based on the mean value theorem.

Comment: Are you sure that the Lipschitz constant is preserved in the equivalence, or there is some factor depending on the dimension $n$ ($f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$) ? Thanks.

Comment: It's preserved. The mean value theorem is applied on the line passing through $x,y$, so the problem becomes one-dimensional.

Comment: can you expand on how the the mean value theorem is applied here?

Comment: @SridharThiagarajan  The following link answers your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2294536/what-does-norm-on-gradient-bounded-of-f-imply-on-the-hessian-of-f?rq=1

Comment: Why using convexity? Even if $\nabla^2 f$ is indefinite, as long as it is symmetric (which is guaranteed if $f$ is twice Frechet differentiable or simply $C^2$), the norm is its largest eigenvalue.

Answer (score 4):

Implication from gradient to Hessian holds true for a twice differentiable function. From the definition of the Hessian of a twice differentiable function $f(\mathbf{x})$, we know that for any vector $\mathbf{v}\in\mathcal{R}^n$

\begin{align}
\nabla^2f(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{v}&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\nabla f(\mathbf{x}+h\mathbf{v})-\nabla f(\mathbf{x})}{h}\\
\implies ||\nabla^2f(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{v}||&\leq\lim_{h\to0}\frac{||\nabla f(\mathbf{x}+h\mathbf{v})-\nabla f(\mathbf{x})||}{|h|}\\
\implies ||\nabla^2f(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{v}||&\leq\lim_{h\to0}L\frac{|h|||\mathbf{v}||}{|h|}\\
\implies ||\nabla^2f(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{v}||&\leq L||\mathbf{v}||
\end{align}

Since this is true for any $\mathbf{v}$, it is also true for the eigenvectors for matrix $\nabla^2f(\mathbf{x})$. If $\mathbf{v}$ is such an eigenvector
\begin{align}
||\nabla^2f(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{v}||&=||\lambda\mathbf{v}||\leq L ||\mathbf{v}||\\
\implies |\lambda|\leq L
\end{align}

So all eigenvalues are upper bounded by $L$

Comment: Please do not post [the same answer twice](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4305430/).  If you believe that one answer is suitable for more than one question, please answer *one* question, and flag the others as duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

It is equivalent for $||\bigtriangledown ^2f(x)||_2 \leq L$ where $||\bigtriangledown ^2f(x)||_2$ means the maximum singular value.