# What does norm on gradient (bounded) of $f$ imply on the hessian of $f$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, lipschitz-functions

Given a $C^2$ function $f$ which has a Lipschitz gradient, that is,

$ || \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y) ||_2 \leq L || x - y ||_2$

Can we prove a bound on the largest eigenvalue of $\nabla^2 f$ ?

What does it mean to say -

$ \lim_{x \rightarrow y} \frac{|| \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y) ||_2}{|| x - y ||_2} \leq L $

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fix vectors $x$ and $y$, and a constant $c>0$.
Let $g(t) = \nabla f(x+tcy)$ and note $g'(t) = [\nabla^2 f(x+tcy)] (cy)$.
By the mean value theorem, there exists some $t_c \in [0,1]$ such that
$$\nabla f(x+cy) - \nabla f(x) = g(1)-g(0) = g'(t_c) = [\nabla^2 f(x+t_ccy)] (cy).$$
Taking the norm of both sides and applying the Lipschitz condition, we have
$$\|[\nabla^2 f(x+t_ccy)]y\| \le L\|y\|.$$

By taking $c \to 0$ and using the fact that $f \in C^2$ and $t_c \in [0,1]$, we have
$$\|[\nabla^2 f(x)]y\| \le L \|y\|.$$
Thus the absolute value of any eigenvalue of $\nabla^2 f(x)$ must be $\le L$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you can use that fact that, if $A$ is a symmetric real matrix, then its maximal eigenvalue $\lambda_{max}(A)$ is characterized by
$$
\lambda_{max}(A) = \max_{\|x\| = 1} \langle Ax, x \rangle.
$$